# Please help me understand the meaning these sentences

Tags: sentence

We have a call about it tonight.  We're trying to close it as a bigger project.  I'll let you know soon.

I would like to understand what 'close it as a bigger project' means. Does it mean the project is being shelved or does it mean that project is being made as a bigger one.

Sorry , I am weak in these things!

Comment: I imagine this is "close" in the sales slang/jargon sense of "reach agreement on a deal".

Comment: In absence of more context, it sounds effectively like "they" hope to increase the size of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it is a bit hard to understand that sentence, but I will give it a try.

> We're trying to close it as a bigger project.

If the project has not yet started, and people are trying to get approval for it, or funding for it, then *closing* the project may be read as ***closing the deal***.

So they may mean, in that case, that they are trying to get approval for the said project by classifying it as a "bigger project" - whatever that means in the context. Possibly, whoever they need the approval or funding from, has separate budgets for differently sized projects, and by "upscaling" this project, it may be possible to secure funding.

On the other hand, if the project *has started* and is currently being executed, *closing* would indicate that it will be ended. In that case, it *does* become obscure why it would be ended "as a bigger project".

One possible interpretation would be that *closing* the project is actually not a negative thing, but describes the project actually being finished well. In that case, the project may have grown beyond its original scope, and by while it originally may have been (seen as) a small project, it actually became quite big.

In order to justify the extra costs and time that that larger scope undoubtedly entailed, it would make sense to redefine the project as larger than it was originally defined. 
I can think of something that started as "redesign of the log in page" and ended up as "rewrite of the complete application authentication structure".

Comment: Woah! That is one amazingly detailed answer. Take a bow @oerkelens .And yes , the project has to start yet and so, I guess it means the former. Hurray!! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The intention , perhaps,  was to convey that the project is about to be divided into smaller parts. The project as a 'Big Project' is about to come to an end. 'Bigger' here perhaps refers to 'Too big to be manageable'.